# Automate Splitting of Series into Equal-Overlapping Sub-series without Subseting in R

Tags: r, split

I got the below `R` trick to split a vector to equal-sizes and overlapping chunks by stating the chunk size to be scalar among other things stated (in the `R` script `lb <- 5`).

```
blocks <- function(lb, ov, n) {

  starts <- unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, lb), seq(lb-ov+1, n, lb))))
  ends <- pmin(starts + lb - 1, n)

  # truncate starts and ends to the first num elements
  num <- match(n, ends)
  head(data.frame(starts, ends), num)
}

ts <- 1:17
n <- length(ts)
lb <- seq(n - 2) + 1 # vector of chunk sizes
lb <- lb[4] # scalar of chunk size =5 in this case
ov <- ceiling(lb/2)
b <- blocks(lb = lb, ov = ov, n = n)
with(b, Map(function(i, j) ts[i:j], starts, ends))
```

The above `R` script returns the result below:

```
##[[1]]
##[1] 1 2 3 4 5

##[[2]]
##[1] 3 4 5 6 7

##[[3]]
##[1]  6  7  8  9 10

##[[4]]
##[1]  8  9 10 11 12

##[[5]]
##[1] 11 12 13 14 15

##[[6]]
##[1] 13 14 15 16 17
```

**What I want**

I want a way to instead of stating sub-vector size to be scalar among others, to state the sub-vector size to be a vector such that `R` works on the first element of the vector of chunk size as a scalar, then switch to the next element of the vector of chunk size to do same as the fist until all the elements of the vector of the chunk size are exhausted. In the below `R` script I set `lb <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)` which is a vector of chunk sizes instead of just one of them (`scalar`).

```
blocks <- function(lb, ov, n) {

  starts <- unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, lb), seq(lb-ov+1, n, lb))))
  ends <- pmin(starts + lb - 1, n)

  # truncate starts and ends to the first num elements
  num <- match(n, ends)
  head(data.frame(starts, ends), num)
}

ts <- 1:17
n <- length(ts)
lb <- seq(2 - 2) + 1 # vector of chunk sizes instead of scalar, in this case `lb = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
ov <- ceiling(lb/2)
b <- blocks(lb = lb, ov = ov, n = n)
with(b, Map(function(i, j) ts[i:j], starts, ends))
```

I got an error message as follows

> Error in seq.default(1, n, lb) : 'by' must be of length 1

**How do I tell `R` to use one element of the vector of chunk sizes at a time**

In that case, I will be expecting the result of in form of a list of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
vblocks <- Vectorize(blocks, c("lb", "ov"), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Then, you can do the vectorization you want:

```
n <- length(ts)
lb <- seq(n - 2) + 1 # vector of chunk sizes
ov <- ceiling(lb/2)
b <- vblocks(lb = lb, ov = ov, n = n)
```

Output

```
> b
[[1]]
   starts ends
1       1    2
2       2    3
3       3    4
4       4    5
5       5    6
6       6    7
7       7    8
8       8    9
9       9   10
10     10   11
11     11   12
12     12   13
13     13   14
14     14   15
15     15   16
16     16   17

[[2]]
   starts ends
1       1    3
2       2    4
3       4    6
4       5    7
5       7    9
6       8   10
7      10   12
8      11   13
9      13   15
10     14   16
11     16   17

[[3]]
  starts ends
1      1    4
2      3    6
3      5    8
4      7   10
5      9   12
6     11   14
7     13   16
8     15   17

[[4]]
  starts ends
1      1    5
2      3    7
3      6   10
4      8   12
5     11   15
6     13   17

[[5]]
  starts ends
1      1    6
2      4    9
3      7   12
4     10   15
5     13   17

[[6]]
  starts ends
1      1    7
2      4   10
3      8   14
4     11   17

[[7]]
  starts ends
1      1    8
2      5   12
3      9   16
4     13   17

[[8]]
  starts ends
1      1    9
2      5   13
3     10   17

[[9]]
  starts ends
1      1   10
2      6   15
3     11   17

[[10]]
  starts ends
1      1   11
2      6   16
3     12   17

[[11]]
  starts ends
1      1   12
2      7   17

[[12]]
  starts ends
1      1   13
2      7   17

[[13]]
  starts ends
1      1   14
2      8   17

[[14]]
  starts ends
1      1   15
2      8   17

[[15]]
  starts ends
1      1   16
2      9   17
```

Comment: Running `with(b, Map(function(i, j) ts[i:j], starts, ends))` afterwards lands me in in error: `Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  object 'starts' not found`

Comment: This is because `b` is a list of dataframes now. Do this instead: `lapply(b, function(x) with(x, Map(function(i, j) ts[i:j], starts, ends)))` @DanielJames

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to apply a rolling function on a window of variable size. I think this can be achieved using the `rollapply` function from the `zoo` package, by supplying a list or a vector to `width` argument.

Comment: can you try it and put the `R` code with output here? Please demonstrate as the answer above did to make your point clear.

Comment: On which part of the script will I apply `roolapply`?

Comment: try this `lapply(lb, ts = ts, function(lb,ts) ts[1:lb]) `

Comment: rollapply works but it turns out it can only return a matrix, so probably not very useful in your case

Comment: let me see the one that produces matrix it can be useful even the `list of lists` is just a step which I have to convert to some matrixes or some vector. It will be an advantage for me.